# Etymology and meaning of ukemi

Tags: judo, aikido, terminology, japanese, falling

I believe that ukemi can be translated as receiving body (受け身). It is what uke (受け, whoever receives the technique) does when nage (投げ thrower) or tori (取り, grabber) applies a technique.

Am I correct in my assumptions?

Are my kanji correct?

---

Japanese SE: [Etymology and meaning of ukemi (受け身?) as part of 合気道](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18025/6910)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Virmaior](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4091/virmaior) at [japanese.se](http://japanese.stackexchange.com) answered my question.  Here is what he said:

> Your kanji are correct. 受け身. You can also write it 受身.
>
> The general meaning of 受け身, however, is not "receiving body" but
>   "passive." Thus, the passive voice "it is written by him" (vs. active
>   "he writes").
>
> I am not familiar with your martial art, but I would guess that it
>   means you take a passive rather than active role in the combat --
>   receiving the action of others and responding to it.

I have added it here for completeness sake. The [full answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18026/6910) can be seen [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18026/6910).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the relevant terms are defined in the *Kodokan New Japanese-English Dictionary of Judo*:

> **uke** (**"receiver"; the thrown; uke**) The person who receives a technique during repetition (uchikomi) or controlled (yakusoku) practice.
>
> **ukemi** (**breakfall**) General term for breakfalls designed to protect the body when thrown.
>
> **ukeru** (**to receive**) To receive a technique or attack from your opponent, or to have a technique applied to you.

Note that these are the definitions of these terms in a judo context, and 受け身 (*ukemi*) and 受ける (*ukeru*) more generally mean "passive one" and "to receive".